# How to use proguard with andengine?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

Could you help me in using the proguard in AndroidStudio? I have an app on andengine lib. All I did was a change in app.gradle of release { minifyEnabled from false to true; and I changed proguard-rules.pro file.

First, I added:

```
-keep class org.andengine.**{
    *;
}
```

and then:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

But none of this did help. It claimed about android.util.FloatMath native methods.

That's what it shows afterall.

```
;
```

Warning:there were 23 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct
   the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

So, is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Okay. I don't think that it is the best solution but I added
    -dontwarn org.andengine.**
in proguard-rules,pro. And now it compiles. But still some files are not uglyfied by proguard. That's what I will look for now.

Comment: I solved it. But the problem was in my own code, so I won't tell about it